# Structure for controlling/monitoring external equipment in C# MVVM?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm writing a small application to control some lab equipment (a temperature controlled chamber, a power supply, and a voltage meter).  Using WPF, C# and MVVM.  Wondering what the patterns are for communicating updates from the equipment back to the ViewModel and View.  I've built a model class for each piece of equipment that exposes properties and methods for things like setting the power supply voltage, turning on the oven, reading the meter's measurement.  I'm wondering about best patterns for notification of changes in properties like power supply mode (switch from voltage limit mode to current limited mode) and current chamber temperature.  I have two different cases:

1) Temperature chamber: The temperature measured in the chamber is slowly moving around on its own and I need to monitor and display the current reading every second.

2) Power Supply: The power supply is usually in a voltage limited mode (keep the voltage constant and let the current vary as needed), but every few hours if the current hits an upper limit it will switch modes to current limit mode (don't allow the current to go over 1amp and let the voltage start to drop as needed).  This is completely controlled by the power supply, but I need to know about this switch of modes when it happens.

I can see ethier setting up a thread in the model to poll the equipment and raising events as the temperature changes or the mode changes.  Could also see keeping the model simple and putting the polling into the ViewModel.  The communication overhead is trivial, so wondering if there is a recommendation for this situation.

Thank you,
Brian

Comment: [Best practice zombies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/1228)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider exposing the hardware data through a service class that implements an interface.  The service class can poll the hardware and raise events as needed.

The interface will allow you to create a mocked implementation for unit testing the application without being hooked up to physical hardware.

The view model for your application should take an instance of the service class in its constructor, hook any events, and unhook when it is ready to shut down.

I wouldn't put the polling directly in the model or view model, as it deals with a specific hardware implementation.  If you can abstract it away as much as possible it makes for far easier testing.

Comment: I like the idea of an interface for testing and isolation. It sounds like your service class is essentially a model by a different name - which isn't really a problem.  If I'm understanding, you would create a service class to monitor the hardware and the model class would exist to control the hardware (i.e. set the chamber temperature, enable/disable temperature control, etc.) Separate from the interface, what is the advantage of putting the polling in another class?

Comment: If you're going to implement service classes, you would want the model and view models to be as simple as possible with no logic other than being POCOs. The service classes should include all the logic needed in your application. If you however do not include a service layer, it makes sense to put the logic in the view models.